# Cordova : Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'. after adding the Share Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-plugins

I just added this plugin into my App running on the Cordova **4.1.2**:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

After the run command

```
cordova build android
```

I got several exceptions during the build:

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

But the Command:

```
cordova build android --debug
```

Is not giving to me any additional info about the problem.

How can i solve it this issue please?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: How you soved this problem??? Is it plugin problem?

Answer (score 0):

In you **AndroidManifest.xml** change this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"    value="9" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue it came with the suggestion add tools:replace="android:value" to  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml